# Align items in ItemsControl horizontally (no xaml)

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

I am looking for a way to set the alignment of the items in an `ItemsControl` so that they are not positioned from top to bottom (default) but from left to right.

I thought there is a property that can easily be set, like

```
ItemsControl crtl = new ItemsControl;
...
ctrl.ContentAlignment = ContentAlignment.Horizontal; // does not exist
```

But it seems this is not the case. There are countless examples in XAML out there to achieve this (usually they use styles or templates or something like that), but I found none in plain C# code. And I don't know how to convert the xaml statements to C# code either.

Can anyone give a hint?

Comment: Let`s try to use property Orientation like in here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052342/itemscontrol-wit‌​h-horizontal-orienta‌​tion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052342/itemscontrol-wit%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bh-horizontal-orienta%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Btion)

Comment: These links may help : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f02db50e-52f6-45d5-b245-6e3ded37bb6e/programmatically-set-itemcontrols-itemspaneltemplate?forum=wpf  & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398000/how-to-set-itemspaneltemplate-to-a-dynamically-created-grid-in-code-behind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let`s try to use property Orientation like in here: [ItemsControl with horizontal orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052342/itemscontrol-wit)‌​‌​h-horizontal-orien‌​ta‌​tion

Here is an example:

```
 var itemsControl = new ItemsControl();    
 var factoryPanel = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
 factoryPanel.SetValue(Panel.IsItemsHostProperty, true);

 factoryPanel.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);    
 var template = new ItemsPanelTemplate {VisualTree = factoryPanel};       
 itemsControl.ItemsPanel = template;
```