# Setting rows of ItemPanelTemplate UniformGrid through C#

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, itemscontrol, uniformgrid

Here's what I have:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="InfoGrid">
       <!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
       <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
               <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                     <UniformGrid Rows="4" Columns="5"                                                  Background="LightGray" />
               </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <!-- ItemTemplate -->
       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                   <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="{Binding Path=BorderThickness}">
                   <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource styleCustomCheckBox}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                   </Border>
              </DataTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

The InfoGrid's itemsource is set to a collection called infoData in the code behind, how can I set the Rows/Columns of this UniformGrid through C# (preferably to variables not contained within infoData)?

I tried binding and using setters but the values don't seem to get applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to access the `ItemsPanel` in the code behind in order to set the columns at runtime.  There are a couple different options for this, including navigating the VisualTree.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319952/how-to-get-listbox-itemspanel-in-code-behind) describes the options and the steps in good detail.