# Reevaluating UniformGrid rows and Columns WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, uniformgrid

I'm trying to create a video player that can play multiple videos at once. I've gotten players working and now I'm trying to allow a user to add additional videos at run time. I'm displaying videos in a uniform grid, which uses a converter to decide how many rows and columns it should generate based on the count of videos. It works fine when you define how many players there are before running, however when I add a player while its running the uniform grid doesn't update the rows or columns. It simply adds another video to whatever structure it had before. Is there anyway that I can force it to reevaluate the rows/columns?

TL;DR: Can I reevaluate the rows and columns of a uniform grid while viewing it? How ?

The xaml for the control is below. 
Additional Infomation That Might be helpful:
1. Players is an ObservableCollection
2. The Control is being presented with a TabControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="Views.AllVideos"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Players}"
                x:Name="AllVideosControl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding Players, Converter={StaticResource CountToColumns}, Mode=OneWay}"
                     Rows="{Binding Players, Converter={StaticResource CountToRows}, Mode=OneWay}"
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                     IsItemsHost="True"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource AccentBrush}"
                BorderThickness="1"
                Margin="5">
          <ls:PanelPreview DataContext="{Binding}"/>
        </Border>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178726/setting-rows-of-itempaneltemplate-uniformgrid-through-c-sharp

Comment: Are you raising `PropertyChanged("Players")` every time the *count* of Players changes? Because there's nothing visible to me there to tell those bindings to update when the count changes. If you can rewrite CountToColumns and CountToRows to take an int, you might as well just  use `{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}, Converter={StaticResource CountToColumns}}`.

Comment: Actually scratch that: I just tested it and `Rows="{Binding Players.Count}` works perfectly for me -- if `Players` is an `ObservableCollection`. Is it? If so, I'd just rewrite those converters to take Players.Count, modulo it, and you're done.

Comment: Yes players is an ObservableCollection, I'll try binding count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that nothing is notifying the binding that the number of items in `Players` has changed: The Binding is sitting there waiting for your viewmodel to tell it there's a new `Players` collection.

But since `Players` is an `ObservableCollection`, it'll raise `PropertyChanged` when it's `Count` changes. So, simplest case:

```
<UniformGrid
    Rows="{Binding Players.Count}"
    ...
    />
```

The following works for me to update the row and column counts as items are added to `Players`. The arithmetic in the converter could use a little work, but the point is that the bindings update `UniformGrid.Rows` and `UniformGrid.Columns` every time `Players` changes. This works because `ObservableCollection` raises `PropertyChanged("Count")` every time an item is added or removed. Because I'm binding to a property of an `ObservableCollection`, the binding subscribes to the `ObservableCollection`'s `PropertyChanged` event, so it knows to update when `Count` changes.

C#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (DataContext as ViewModel).Players.Add($"Player {(DataContext as ViewModel).Players.Count + 1}");
    }

    private void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((DataContext as ViewModel).Players.Count > 0)
            (DataContext as ViewModel).Players.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<String> _players = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<String> Players
    {
        get { return _players; }
    }
}

public class RowsColumnsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt((int)value));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ItemsControl
        Grid.Row="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Players}"
        >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid
                    Rows="{Binding Players.Count, Converter={StaticResource RowsColumns}}"
                    Columns="{Binding Players.Count, Converter={StaticResource RowsColumns}}"
                    />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button 
            Content="Add Player" 
            Click="AddButton_Click" 
            Margin="2" 
            Width="100" 
            />
        <Button 
            Content="Remove Player" 
            Click="RemoveButton_Click"
            Margin="2" 
            Width="100" 
            />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned that Players is an ObservableCollection, and that it definitely is updated via the binding as I do get more players showing up, its just the layout that is wrong

Comment: @ScottMaher You said you saw items in the grid, so I figured that was probably the case.

Comment: Hey Ed, your comment suggesting I bind directly to count worked like a charm. If you'll edit your answer to include it I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: @ScottMaher Done. But I think AnjumSKhan's answer below may be the more correct one.

Comment: No, his suggestion was to not set the rows/columns, but that actually is necessary for reasons I left out of the question, unsetting them was my first line of thought as well. Second is it's MVVM so any event in the code behind couldn't and shouldn't get a reference to the collection, and the collection should definitely not be anywhere near the control. Thanks for your help

Comment: @ScottMaher Ah, OK. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Setting `Rows` and `Columns` isn't needed at all. Everything will work without them too. `UniformGrid` will place everything uniformly inside whatever container.

If still you want to use `Binding` , then following works for me , `Cols` are fixed here. `Converters` are not need.

```
    void Players_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Rows = (int)Math.Ceiling(Players.Count / Cols);
    }
```