# Set ItemsPanelTemplate UniformGrid Rows and Cols

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I set the `Rows` and `Columns` of that `UniformGrid` in c# code behind?

```
   <ListBox x:Name="galerielb"   Margin="10,0,0,10"  
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SimpleListBoxItem}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="10" Columns="6"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7319952/1136211

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's just a template, you could create a new one and set the `ItemsPanel` property directly:

```
FrameworkElementFactory ug = new FrameworkElementFactory(UniformGrid);
ug.SetValue(UniformGrid.RowsProperty, 10);
ug.SetValue(UniformGrid.ColumnsProperty, 6);
galerielb.ItemsPanel = new ItemsPanelTemplate(ug);
```